# Parse a csv with new lines

Tags: php, csv, parsing

I need to parse a csv but this csv is malformed, in some fields there are new lines (\n) that break my parser.

Is there any way to avoid that ? Currently i'm parsing like that :

```
if($file){
   $full_path = DRUPAL_ROOT . '/' . file_stream_wrapper_get_instance_by_uri($file->uri)->getDirectoryPath() . '/' . file_uri_target($file->uri);
   $csvData = file_get_contents($full_path);
   if (!mb_detect_encoding($csvData, 'UTF-8')) $csvData = utf8_encode($csvData);
   //$lines = explode(",", $csvData);
   $lines = array_map("str_getcsv", file($full_path), array_fill(0, count(file($full_path)), ';'));
   dsm($csvData);
   foreach ($lines as $line){
   dsm($line);
}
```

But when the str_getcsv find a `\n` he create a new line and I can't correctly parse the csv (I can't modify the csv it's from another person).

Maybe there is a way to remove the `\n` from fields but not from the end of the line ?

Example of the field who have line breakers in my csv
[image: Example of the field who have line breakers in my csv]

Comment: Yes the data is malformed, there is some line breakers in one field and the str_getcsv seems to work fine, but he create a new line for every line breaker

Comment: _“there is some line breakers in one field”_ - that does not necessarily mean it is “malformed”, if a field enclosure character is used. Show an example please.

Comment: There is no enclosure it's why it doesn't work, see the edit

Comment: Well then it is sh*t data that should be _rejected_ to begin with. Where do you get this crap from, can’t you tell them to fix it?

Comment: _“Maybe there is a way to remove the \n from fields but not from the end of the line ?”_ - well how exactly do you define “end of the line” then?

Comment: I can't tell them to fix it there is like 1000 row like this, it's for a customer who need to import his old data to a new website but he only have this csv, no database

Comment: Unless those line breaks are limited to occur inside one specific “column” only, there is no way for you to determine with absolute certainty where a full “row” of data ends. So at best you could try and write an algorithm that tries to make an educated guess, but most likely someone will have to check the result afterwards anyway.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that str_getcsv() cannot be used by itself to do this.

Have a look at the [comments](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php#111665) of the str_getcsv function. There are examples of how other people have already solved exactly your problem.

Comment: But if I want to use this I need to change all line breakers to quote ? I can't do that